AppwriteException: Invalid `email` param: Value must be a valid email address and AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (account)
I am doing my first React Native App using Expo and I use Expo Go to view the output in my physical Android Device, when I run the project It works properly in the Web Properly but when I try to login using my device it shows these errors:
 LOG  [AppwriteException: User (role: guests) missing scope (account)]
 LOG  Email: jomonantony@gmail.com
 LOG  [AppwriteException: Invalid `email` param: Value must be a valid email address]

Codes
AppwriteConfig.js:
import APPWRITE_CONFIG from './config'
import { Client, Account, ID } from "appwrite";

class AppwriteAuthServices {
    client = new Client();
    account;

    constructor() {
        this.client
            .setEndpoint(APPWRITE_CONFIG.PROJECT_URL)
            .setProject(APPWRITE_CONFIG.PROJECT_ID);
        this.account = new Account(this.client);
    }

    async getCurrentUser() {
        try {
            const promise = await this.account.get()
            
            if (promise) {
                console.log(promise);
                return promise
            } else {
                return null
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }
    
    async LoginUsingEmailAndPassword({email, password}) {
        try {
            const promise = await this.account.createEmailPasswordSession(encodeURIComponent(email), String(password));
            
            if (promise) {
                this.getCurrentUser()
                alert("login and sign-up successful")
                return promise
            } else {
                return 'Account Not Created!!!'
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
    }

    async createAccountUsingEmailAndPassword({email, password}) {
        email = encodeURIComponent(email)
        password = String(password)

        try {
            const promise = await this.account.create(ID.unique(), email, password)
            
            if (promise) {
                this.LoginUsingEmailAndPassword({email, password})
            } else {
                return 'Account Not Created!!!'
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            if (error == 'AppwriteException: A user with the same id, email, or phone already exists in this project.') {
                this.LoginUsingEmailAndPassword({email, password})
            }
            console.log(error);
        }
    }


    async LogOutUsingEmailAndPassword() {
        try {
            const promise = await this.account.deleteSessions();
            
            if (promise) {
                return promise
            } else {
                return null
            }
            
        } catch (error) {
            throw error
        }
    }
    
}

const appwriteAuthServices = new AppwriteAuthServices();

export default appwriteAuthServices;

Index.js:
import { View, Pressable, Text, TextInput } from 'react-native';
import Styles from './config/Style';
import appwriteAuthServices from "./config/AppwriteConfig";
import { useState } from "react";


export default function LoginSignup() {
    const [EmailPassword, setEmailPassword] = useState({
        email : '',
        password: ''
    });
    const [signUp, setSignUp] = useState(false);

    function isValidEmail(email) {
        const emailRegex = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]+$/;
        return emailRegex.test(email);
    }

    function HandleSignUp() {
        if (!isValidEmail(EmailPassword.email)) {
            alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
            return;
        }
        console.log("Email:", EmailPassword.email);
        appwriteAuthServices.createAccountUsingEmailAndPassword(EmailPassword);
    }

    function HandleLogIn() {
        if (!isValidEmail(EmailPassword.email)) {
            alert("Please enter a valid email address.");
            return;
        }
        console.log("Email:", EmailPassword.email);
        appwriteAuthServices.LoginUsingEmailAndPassword(EmailPassword);
    }

    return (
        <View style={Styles.LoginContainer}>
            { 
                signUp ? 
                <Text>Already have an account?<Pressable onPress={() => setSignUp(!signUp)}><Text style={Styles.ColorBlue}>Login</Text></Pressable></Text> 
                : 
                <Text>Don't have an account?<Pressable onPress={() => setSignUp(!signUp)}><Text style={Styles.ColorBlue}>Sign up</Text></Pressable></Text> 
            }
            <TextInput value={EmailPassword.email} onChangeText={(text) => setEmailPassword({...EmailPassword, email: text})} placeholder='Email' autoCapitalize='none' style={Styles.inputText} />
            <TextInput value={EmailPassword.password} onChangeText={(text) => setEmailPassword({...EmailPassword, password: text})} placeholder='Password' autoCapitalize='none' secureTextEntry={true} style={Styles.inputText} />


            { 
                signUp ? 
                <Pressable onPress={EmailPassword && HandleSignUp} style={Styles.Button}><Text style={Styles.ColorWhite}>Create Account</Text></Pressable>
                : 
                <Pressable onPress={EmailPassword && HandleLogIn} style={Styles.Button}><Text style={Styles.ColorWhite}>Log In</Text></Pressable>
            }

<Pressable onPress={appwriteAuthServices.LogOutUsingEmailAndPassword} style={Styles.Button}><Text style={Styles.ColorWhite}>Log out</Text></Pressable>
            
        </View>
    );
}

Need your help solving this!
I tried to solve it but I don't have a lot of knowledge about React Native and Appwrite, so I failed then I asked chatgpt 3 but it failed too. now I am here to ask you!
